# C# Virtual method call in constructor - how to refactor?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class for database-agnostic cursor actions.
Derived from that, there are classes that implement the abstract methods for handling database-specific stuff.

The problem is, the base class ctor needs to call an abstract method - when the ctor is called, it needs to initialize the database-specific cursor.

**I know why this shouldn't be done, I don't need *that* explanation!**

This is my first implementation, that obviously doesn't work - it's the textbook "wrong way" of doing it.
The overridden method accesses a field from the derived class, which is not yet instantiated:

```
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private readonly int m_rowCount;
    protected CursorReader(string sqlCmd)
    {
         m_rowCount = CreateCursor(sqlCmd); //virtual call !
    }
    protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);

    //...other (non-abstract) methods that assume a cursor exists
}

public class SqlCursorReader : CursorReader
{
    private SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;

    public SqlCursorReader(string sqlCmd, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        m_sqlConnection = sqlConnection;     //field initialized here
    }
    protected override int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd)
    {
        //uses not-yet-initialized member *m_sqlConnection*
        //so this throws a NullReferenceException
        var cursor = new SqlCursor(sqlCmd, m_sqlConnection); 
        cursor.Create();
        return cursor.Count();
    }
}
```

I will follow up with an answer on my attempts to fix this...

### UPDATE

The overridden method `CreateCursor()` creates an *actual* cursor in a database. This is paramount for the correct functioning of many methods that were ommitted from the class.
`CreateCursor()` must be called in the base ctor in order for the class to be in a consistent state when the ctor returns. I've slightly updated the code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

You could always have a lazy property that gets the count.

```
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private int? m_rowCount;
    protected CursorReader()
    {

    }
    protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);
    protected int RowCount {
      get {
          if (m_RowCount == null)
          {
             m_RowCount = CreateCursor(sql);
          }
          return m_RowCount.Value;
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: @hunter its the same thing. for `Nullable` types, I like to check for `null`.

Comment: does `CursorReader` know what `sql` is?

Comment: Your getter prevents the JIT to use the inlining feature.

Comment: @CSharper: Well, it could be one-lined (and inlined) using `return (rowCount ?? (rowCount = CreateCursor(sql))).Value` so it's not that big of a deal.

Comment: I do not mean, that you cannot write it on one line! But the JIT can only use inlining on simple getters. And your Code isn't simple.

Comment: @Daniel Please read my update to the question - I can't postpone calling CreateCursor(). The integrity of the instance of CursorReader depends on it being called at object initialization. Or I could add checks for "IsCursorInitialized" in each of the (omitted) methods of the class (and there are a lot of them).

Comment: @hunter - the sql string is an invariant for the instance - we can safely assume it's given as a param in the ctor and saved in a private/protected field of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private int? m_rowCount = null;
    private int rowCount { get { return m_rowCount = m_rowCount ?? CreateCursor(sqlCmd); } }
    protected CursorReader() { }
    protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);
}
```

Comment: does `CursorReader` know what `sqlCmd` is?

Comment: @hunter It's just a snippet from the OP. I assume it's exposed but the real abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to separate your logic into a constructor and an initialization.

```
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private readonly int m_rowCount;
    protected CursorReader()
    {

    }

    protected void Init()
    {
         m_rowCount = CreateCursor(sqlCmd); //virtual call !
    }

    protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);
}
```

This would require you to call `Init()` on every new instance, but it's the best solution that I can think of.

Note that `Init` could be called from derived classes like you mentioned, but I think it would be simpler to call it from calling code. There are a lot of types that use this pattern, and even though it requires more code, it's not a bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "it would be simpler to call it from calling code" ? Also, check the update to my question - CreateCursor() should really get called while constructing the object. Maybe take a look at my own answer, it looks like it's headed in a similar direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 2nd direction I'm thinking about:

In order to side-step the chicken-and-egg problem, while allowing eager creation of the cursor, some abstraction is in order.

In the base class, the virtual call tries to access a not-yet-initialized field in the derived class. So let's extract the functionality of creating a cursor in a different class. The base class isn't interested in how it's created, it's just a step in a larger algorithm.

The gist of this approach, to me, looks similar to the [*strategy pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - a master class knows the general steps of an algorithm, while actual implementation details for the steps are plugged-in at runtime.

```
public interface ICursorCreator {
    int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);
}
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private readonly int m_rowCount;
    protected CursorReader(string sqlCmd, ICursorCreator creator)
    {
         m_rowCount = creator.CreateCursor(sqlCmd); //no longer a virtual call 
    }
    //protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);//no longer needed

    //...other (non-abstract) methods that assume a cursor exists
}

//move the logic of creating a cursor in a separate class, and pass an instance of that to the base class. 
public SqlCursorCreator: ICursorCreator {
    private SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;
    public SqlCursorCreator(SqConnection conn){
        m_sqlConnection = conn;
    }
    public int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd)
    {
        var cursor = new SqlCursor(sqlCmd, m_sqlConnection); 
        cursor.Create();
        return cursor.Count();
    }
}

public class SqlCursorReader : CursorReader
{
    //private SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;//no longer needed

    //by saving the connection in the factory, it will be available when needed later
    public SqlCursorReader(string sqlCmd, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
        :this(sqlCmd, new SqlCursorCreator(sqlConnection))
    { }
    protected SqlCursorReader(string sqlCmd, SqlCursorCreator creator)
        : base(sqlCmd, creator)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st try was to move the virtual call out of the base ctor, but it has some down-sides:

- m_rowCount is no longer readonly
- the derived class AND ALL FUTURE DERIVED CLASSES need to call the base class Initialize() method.

-

```
public abstract class CursorReader
{
    private int m_rowCount;//no longer read-only
    protected CursorReader()
    {
        //no virtual call here
    }
    protected abstract int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd);
    protected void Initialize()
    {
         //virtual call moved here
         m_rowCount = CreateCursor(sqlCmd); //virtual call !
    }
}
public class SqlCursorReader : CursorReader
{
    private SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;

    public SqlCursorReader(string sqlCmd, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        m_sqlConnection = sqlConnection;

        //the derived classes NEED to call the base class' Initialize() 
        Initialize();
    }
    protected override int CreateCursor(string sqlCmd)
    {
        //uses not-yet-initialized member m_sqlConnection
        var cursor = new CustomCursor(sqlCmd, m_sqlConnection); 
        return cursor.Count();
    }
}
```

I especially don't like the 2nd bullet...

Comment: Is this an answer or an update? It looks like it should just be part of the question.

Comment: @Kendall It's one possible answer. I was hoping to get some constructive criticism for it.